# A SIMPLER way to use iCloud with MonoTouch?

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios, icloud, icloud-api

I need to add iCloud to my MonoTouch iPhone/iPad app, allowing the User to store the app data in the cloud. Unfortunately it seems that iCloud is way too complicated for something that, from my point of view, should be essentially reduced to three simple methods (pseudocode):

1) bool SaveFileToiCloud(AppIDstring, @"filename.dat", file_stream);

2) Datetime GetFileLastUpdatedTimeOniCloud(AppIDstring, @"filename.dat")

3) byte[] LoadFileFromiCloud(AppIDstring, @"filename.dat");

I've read and watched all the "Using iCloud with MonoTouch" Seminar:

Slides for this session:

http://www.slideshare.net/Xamarin/using-icloud-with-monotouch

Video for this session:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0MojsFRfjI

Code for this session:

https://github.com/xamarin/Seminars/tree/master/2012-03-22-iCloud

Unfortunately the seminar confirmed me that iCloud management is overcomplicated.

Is there some other and quicker way to use iCloud in MonoTouch?

Does exist some open source framework or library able to wrap all that iCloud configuration and setup code and just give us something simple like the three methods above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another option is just to store files in your app's `Documents` folder.  iCloud will automatically back that folder up and you don't have to do anything about it.  Keep in mind, you should only back up data created by your app's users.

Comment: Is it really simple as jonathanpeppers said? Because that is very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud is still very recent so you're unlikely to receive an immediate answer for an easier API. IOW I'm sure other people feels just like you and that it will, eventually, lead to easier alternatives.

If you want to make this happen faster then I suggest you to fill this request to [Xamarin's User Voice](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-suggestions). I think a Cloud-like **Mobile** API, usable with iOS, Android and Windows Phone, would be a great addition to the products.